# How to repair jekyll and bundle installation

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, jekyll

The command `bundle exec jekyll serve` stopped to work correctly on my system, and leads now to this error:

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/bundle: /usr/bin/ruby2.5: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I don't know how it happened, but gem tells me that jekyll and bundle are not installed, when actually they are present in a different path:

```
$ which gem
/usr/bin/gem

$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

$ which bundler
/usr/local/bin/bundler

$ which jekyll
/usr/local/bin/jekyll

$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

$ gem --version
3.1.2

$ ruby --version
ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

I don't know how to undo that. I looked around and there are several ways to repair this (export a path, reinstall ruby), but I'm unsure which way is the less likely to break my system more.

Comment: I ended up following these instructions (https://bundler.io/doc/troubleshooting.html) and this fix the problem. `gem install bundler` `bundle update --bundler`. I still don't understand what happened and why/how I fixed it, so if you have any idea, please comment :)

Comment: For me running `gem update jekyll` afterwards was also needed, to fix the problem. See https://jekyllrb.com/docs/upgrading/